# Word for something that is checked?

Tags: single-word-requests

Context: A tool that checks various settings or configurations to verify compliance.

Further context:
If I were a health safety inspector, I would go to a restaurant and I might review their meat temperatures, cleaning logs, sanitary documentation, food handling practices, etc...

If I were writing about this on a website, there might be a section that goes like this:

---

> **Things that are checked**
>
> Food safety is a serious matter! When we review your restaurant, we
> will check:
>
> - Meat temperatures (both in fridge and when served)
> - Cleaning logs (kitchen, bathroom, and dining area)
> - Sanitary documentation (is it documented where to find gloves or how often a surface needs to be wiped down?)
> - Food handling practices (do chefs wear mouth covers and hair nets)

---

Im wondering if there is a one-word, accusative-type word for "Things that are checked." Like in German there might be a compound word for DasCheckedThingsen, but we dont readily use such constructions in English.

Comment: This question is *extremely* vague.  Please add more context.  Nonetheless, I will try to answer your question with what you have written at the moment.  Some words that I would use are: "examined," "inspected," "verified," "reviewed," "tested," "scanned," "assessed," and maybe a few others.  Note: due to the ambiguity of your question, I tried to include a variety of words; some of them may not be applicable to your situation.  Please ensure that the word you choose is correct by reading their definitions.

Comment: Yes, further context is needed. Just where is this tool used, by whom and to what purpose: inspecting for explosives or tooth decay?.

Comment: @JohnB.  Thanks for the feedback. Added more details not sure if it heps

Comment: @Elliot Thanks for the feedback. Added more details not sure if it heps

Comment: With this new context, I would probably use "examine," "inspect," "review," "assessed," and (potentially) "tested" from the list I wrote earlier.

Comment: "criteria", or simply "tests", could be used?

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the word **check** itself? The title of the list actually uses it: *things that are checked*. So, why look for a different word? If it's a list of things that are checked, then each thing *is* … **checked**. And things that are *checked* are **checks**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You go through a **checklist**. From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/checklist)

> **checklist**
> NOUN
>
> A list of items required, things to be done, or points to be considered, used as a reminder.
>
> *You need to create an operations manual that is essentially a series of checklists.*

A checklist can be an informal list of things to do (a reminder) or a series of essential steps to take, as a formal procedure, for example pre-flight checks in an aircraft.

Comment: And to go in a checklist, you have checkpoints. A [checkpoint](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/checkpoint) is defined as: a point or item, especially in a procedure, for notation, inspection, or confirmation.